# Uninstalling New Relic on Django

Tags: django, apache, wsgi, newrelic

I installed New Relic on my website and now that I removed it my wsgi is messed up. I think it's this command (step 4 from [here](https://newrelic.com/docs/python/python-agent-quick-start))

`NEW_RELIC_CONFIG_FILE=newrelic.ini newrelic-admin run-program python manage.py run_gunicorn`

That needs to be undone, but can't figure out how to. I'm pretty sure it's that line because I checked my apache log and it is complaining about how New Relic is missing (I already removed the other stuf).

Has anyone uninstalled New Relic from their Python/Django site? I can't find instructions on their site for uninstalling.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this problem: there was a new-relic import in my .wsgi file. You can do `grep -r ./ newrelic` from within your codebase to find any newrelic imports or code that you need to remove.